# Is it possible to load a external css "specific some lines" in a html?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to load a external css **"specific some lines"** in a html?
For example : I have a page with some div, and i want the page load **only specific some lines** from css, not entire css, see snippet below. Are there have some way to show **only** div1 and div2 style, not all four ?

```css
.class1 {
 background-color:#FC0;
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
}
.div1 {
 background-color:#CCC;
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
}
.class2 {
 background-color:#F00;
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
}
.div2 {
 background-color:#FFC;
 width:300px;
 height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="class1">class1 text (I don't want this css)</div>
<div class="div1">div1 text</div>
<div class="class2">class2 text (I don't want this css)</div>
<div class="div2">div2 text</div>
```

Comment: Do not write that class to the div.

Comment: Also, read [How to Ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before asking questions.

Comment: Can you include your company policy?

Answer (score 0):

Separate your css files, and link to only the css file containing the css you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to separate my css. (Because the company policy)

Comment: Very unusual policy.

Judging by your example, you can just remove the classes on your class text.

Comment: E.g. <div>class1 text (I don't want this css)</div>
<div class="div1">div1 text</div>
<div>class2 text (I don't want this css)</div>
<div class="div2">div2 text</div>

Comment: Unfortunately, that is also not possible. (Because the idiot boss). And i can't use CSS Comments, must be load a external css "specific some lines". Anyone can help ?

Comment: @user3555766 does creating another css file and override the class you don't want also violate your company policy?